# SelectList with 2 Tables info

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

These are my SQL Tables:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [FunctionID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[CreateDate]
      ,[CreateBy]
      ,[LastUpdate]
      ,[LastUpdateBy]
  FROM [PortugalTrailsCore_DB].[dbo].[TBL_UserFunction]

SELECT TOP (1000) [UserID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Username]
      ,[Password]
      ,[Active]
      ,[OperationPlaceID]
      ,[SigavUserId]
      ,[SigavUserLogin]
      ,[CreateDate]
      ,[CreateBy]
      ,[LastUpdate]
      ,[LastUpdateBy]
  FROM [PortugalTrailsCore_DB].[dbo].[TBL_User]
```

---

I want to create in my MVC, in view create 1 `SelectList` with the title with the names of `TBL_UserFunction` (Names) and the items are the names of `TBL_User`.
Ex.

4 `SelectLists` each one with 1 of the names of `TBL_UserFunction`, and the info of each `SelectList` with ALL the names of `TBL_User`.

Any suggestions?

Here is what I have so far to create the view:

```
<div class="row form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.profileModels, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.DropDownList("listF1IDs", (SelectList)ViewBag.Function2)
        @Html.DropDownList("list1IDs", (SelectList)ViewBag.Roles, "comercial")
    </div>
</div>

public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(db.TBL_Profile.ToList(), "ProfileID", "ProfileName");
    ViewBag.Function2 = new SelectList(db.TBL_UserFunction.ToList(), "FunctionID", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Hi Pedro, can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: Hello. at the moment i ive separated selectlists.